# How to solve ValidatePostSize error in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, post, laravel-5

I keep receiving this error whenever I try to post a form in a Laravel 5 app.

> ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)↵at
> ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in
> Pipeline.php (line 148)↵at
> Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))in
> Pipeline.php (line 53)↵at
> Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))in
> CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)↵at
> CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in
> Pipeline.php (line 148)↵at
> Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))in
> Pipeline.php (line 53)↵at
> Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php
> (line 102)↵at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))in Kernel.php (line
> 151)↵at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))in Kernel.php
> (line 116)↵at Kernel->handle(object(Request))in index.php (line 54)↵↵↵

I tried adding these lines in .htaccess according to [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-set-the-max-post-size-and-the-max-upload-size-in-Laravel) answer:

```
php_value post_max_size=15M 
php_value upload_max_filesize=15M
```

I also commented out these lines according to [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-posttoolargeexception-in-validatepostsizephp-line-22) answer

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
//        if ($request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH') > $this->getPostMaxSize()) {
//            throw new PostTooLargeException;
//        }

        return $next($request);
   }
```

How can I kill size validation on this form?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but i would try to restart apache after changing .htaccess/php.ini/httpd.conf